# Container cuts off when scrolling up on mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a survey page, where the body has `background-color: #A71930`, and a container with `background-color: white`, which holds the `<form>`, like this on a desktop:

[image: desktop example]

I have added these @media queries for mobile devices:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #survey-container {
    width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-height: 600px) {
  #survey-container {
    height: 100%;
    }
  }
```

These queries make the page look like this on a phone screen:

[image: mobile example]

This is good for now, but my issue is when you scroll to the bottom, then start going back up, this happens here:

[image: the issue with the container]

As you can see, when you scroll up, part of the container is cut off at the bottom, still leaving the `<form>` content. You can see for yourself [here](http://jdipasquale.com/giants-survey.html). So, what is causing this problem, and how can it be fixed? My full code can be viewed below(the issue does not seem to occur in codepen, so only try the issue in a mobile browser):
https://codepen.io/jerryd2304/pen/qvERZL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate this in Mac/Safari (12.0.3), but not Chrome or Firefox.

**Fix 1:**

Remove the `height: 100%` altogether.

**Fix 2:**

Change `height` to `min-height`:

```
@media all and (max-height: 600px) {
  #survey-container {
    min-height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Either way, the problem is resolved:

[image]

Comment: `min-height` works great! Thank you, will accept this answer